# How do I add text in the payment section within snipcart?

Tags: html, snipcart

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this post, I have a static site configured as e-commerce using Snipcart, I have managed to change some aspects that I need, but I have not been able to access and modify the payment section (step 3) to add text. This is the code that I declared so that Snipcart can change the content shown by default:

`<div hidden id="snipcart" data-api-key="XXX" data-config-add-product-behavior="none" data-templates-url="https://harvestoflove.mx/plugins/snipcart-templates.html"></div>`

This is the code that I have in the URL that I declared so that Snipcart can edit the content that it shows by default in the adress section (step1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Templates</title></head>

    <body>
     <div id="snipcart-templates">
      <address-fields>
       <div>
        <fieldset class="snipcart-form__set">
         <div class="snipcart-form__row">

          <div class="snipcart-form__field snipcart-form__cell--large">
           <snipcart-label class="snipcart__font--tiny" for="address1">
            {{ $localize('address_form.address1') }}
           </snipcart-label>
           <snipcart-input name="address1"></snipcart-input>
           <snipcart-error-message name="address1"></snipcart-error-message>
          </div>

          <div>
           varias divs como la de arriba para modificar y agregar aspectos del paso 1 
          </div>


         </div>
        </fieldset>
       </div>
      </address-fields>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have not been able to insert code that helps modify the aspects of step 3 (payment) since I want to add text.

Answer (score 0):

The template you'll need to override to customize the payment form is [documented here](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/themes/default/reference#component-payment). The credit card form itself can't be overridden since it's in an `iframe`. You can still change colors though, this is documented [here](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/sdk/api#customizationregisterpaymentformcustomization).